# Roles for Sonata Admins

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am making use of SonataAdminBundle **without** SonataUserBundle, but with FOSUserBundle only. The reason is because I use Symfony 3, and SonataUserBundle doesn't work there.

Now, I have 24 Admin services. I need to modify only one Admin Class so that users can't create new users and that they can't modify other users' profiles. Only Super Admin is able to do that.

But does that mean that I have to write 24 Admins' roles out like this?

```
ROLE_OPTICKS_ACCESS:
    - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO_LIST
    - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO_VIEW
    - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO_CREATE
    - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO_EDIT
    - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO_DELETE
    - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO_EXPORT
```

I will then end up with about 144 of this lines in my security.yml. And then I can remove the two lines that says `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_CREATE` and `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_EDIT` and then still figure a way out to make it only possible to edit his own profile.

Can anybody assist? Is this the best way to do it? Am I doing it right?

Because I was just thinking of something like this;

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $securityContext = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker');

    if (!$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
        $collection->remove('create');
        $collection->remove('edit');
    }
}
```

But apparently I'm doing it the wrong way around, and I get an error as well saying;

> The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL

Please, I need desperately help.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement your own security handler

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: app.security.handler
```

This is a service, and you have to implement your own `isGranded` method

```
public function isGranted(AdminInterface $admin, $attributes, $object = null)
{
    if ($admin instanceof FooAdmin) {
        return $this->securityChecker->isGranted("ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO");
    }
}
```

In this way any who has a `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FOO` role will be able to make anythins with `FooAdmin`. It's just a sketch, of course, you may implement more complex logic.